# Automation through Selenium Python Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am testing Browser Automation through Selenium/Python.
When I open the url (https://www.southwest.com/air/low-fare-calendar/select-dates.html?adultPassengersCount=1&currencyCode=USD&departureDate=2021-02-01&destinationAirportCode=DEN&originationAirportCode=ATL&passengerType=ADULT&returnAirportCode=&returnDate=&tripType=oneway) through normal chrome, it works. But when opening through Selenium/Python, it displays an error on the webpage. Looks like source website is expecting some cookies. How do I resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I see the same error on accessing the url even manually.

Comment: what if you visit https://www.southwest.com/air/low-fare-calendar/ and select "one way" from Atlanta to Denver. This will direct you to next page which is the link on my original post. Now if you copy this link and paste into new tab it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
options=ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option(
    "excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
```

It detects automation use this options and it will work

Comment: I tried with headless mode and this driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="flyout-trigger list-box"]').click() creates an error. but it does work with non headless mode. any idea. below is the error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: i am not getting any error could you ask as a different question with relevant screen shots

Comment: trye adding wait or sleep and see if any error is there

Comment: PDHide - here is the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65928302/automating-selenium-headless-mode-errors