# Automating Selenium Headless mode errors

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I tried automating the below code with headful mode and it works but not in headless mode. Throws a lot of javascript errors and finally says unable to find the element.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.headless = True
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
chrome_options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.southwest.com/air/low-fare-calendar/select-dates.html?adultPassengersCount=1&currencyCode=USD&departureDate=2021-02-01&destinationAirportCode=MCO&originationAirportCode=ALB&passengerType=ADULT&returnAirportCode=&returnDate=&tripType=oneway')
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="flyout-trigger list-box"]').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_id("Listbox_10--item-3").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot_after.png")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Try adding window size in options this sometimes happens with setting it to headless.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan - it didnt work. this is my python code.
`chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")`

Comment: It seems to determine that it's a bot from what I can tell when it opens in the normal view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I went to the driver.get() it had some errors I am not 100% sure if it's bot detection which when I disabled navigator.webdriver it seemed to function correctly.

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/webdriver if anyone is looking into this , its enabled by default in headless mode